# Understanding how Prime Polynomials are applied to LFSRs?

Tags: polynomials, applications

In doing some research on [LFSRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR) I understand that a primitive polynomial can determine what taps to be used to create an LFSR that has as many bits as the degree of the polynomial that will cycle through all non-zero states. E.G. A primitive polynomial whose coefficients are in GF(2) such as $x^4+x^3+1$ implies that a 4 bit LFSR will cycle through every possible non-zero state once and only once if the 4th bit and the 3rd bit are used as taps.

I don't understand the connection between a primitive polynomial and the taps of an LFSR. I never would have looked at a primitive polynomial and thought "let's make those bits in a register and xor them... etc" and made the connection. Can somebody explain this magic?

Comment: (If I have understood it correctly the following applies to Galois LFSRs only, so I will only make it a comment.) The trick is that if we represent the state $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)$ as a polynomial $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$, then the new state (after a single clock tick) $(a_3,a_0,a_1+a_3,a_2)$ corresponds to the polynomial $q(x)=x p(x)+a_3(x^4+x^3+1)$ that is congruent to $xp(x)$ modulo the feedback polynomial. The primitive polynomials $r(x)$ of degree $d$ have the property that the coset $x+(r(x))$ generates the multiplicative group of the finite field $GF(2^d)=GF(2)[x]/(r(x))$.

Comment: (cont'd) and this explains why the state vector cycles through all the non-zero states. I never remember how the polynomial algebra plays out for Fibonacci LFSRs. IIRC the reciprocal polynomial comes into play or the clock runs backwards or something like that. Sorry - it's getting too late here for me to think straight :-/

Comment: Take a look at John Kerl's ["Computation in Finite Fields"](http://www.johnkerl.org/doc/ffcomp.pdf), part V (sadly the document is incomplete).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I'm pretty self taught in this field so there's A LOT I have to learn starting with what is $xp(x)$? Don't be afraid to talk to me like I'm stupid. In Finite Fields and Galois Theory, I kind of am.

Comment: A good understanding of this problem is nicely explained here: http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece553/handouts/LFSR-notes.PDF

Answer (score 2):

To understand the connection between the taps and Primitive Polynomials, it is important to look into Galois Field or Finite field in depth. However, I would try to summarise it: 
LFSR circuit basically performs multiplication on a "field". A field usually defined as set with two operations defined ( multiplication and additions) and other laws such as associative and distributive laws hold.

Finite fields are called Galois Field such Binary numbers (0 and 1) with XOR (= modulo 2 addition) and AND (multiplication) is a GF(2).

Polynomials with binary coefficient also form a GF(2) with each term (x^n) either present(1*x^n) or absent (0*x^n). Addition and Multiplication of these polynomials forms a field: Add (= XOR of each term) and Multiply (Shifting to the left).

[image: Addition]                    [image: Multiplication]

A primitive polynomial is one that cannot be factored. And as a fact: for any degree there is exists at least one prime polynomial ( Look for Primitive Polynomial Table).

Taking the result of the above multiplication, and modulo a prime polynomial, we can form GF(2^n).

As an example: 
Consider a 4 bit LFSR with polynomials x^4 + x + 1. With LFSR=> 
[image: 4 Bit LFSR]

The Pattern it generates : 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000, 0011, 0110, 1100, 1011 ....

Notice that whenever MSB (Q4) is one, the current register values are xored with "10011" or if its zero, the values are only shifted left.

This can also be explained in terms of primitive elements: 
a^3 = 1*x^3 + 0*x^2 + 0*x^1 + 0*x^0 
a^4 = 1*x^4 xor x^4 + x + 1 = x + 1 = "0011"

In summary : 
Galois Field Multiplication => Shift left in Hardware
Taking the result mod p(X) => Xoring when MSB is 1

Hope this helps.

Source: Compilations from Study notes from University of Munich and Berkeley.